# add float div to this flexible layout

Tags: html, css

I'm working with [this layout](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DVAcV/9/).

I want to add a `div`  next to `content` `div`.
I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <header>here is the header </header>
    <div class="sidebar">my sidebar content</div>
<div class="content">
/my text
</div>
<footer>
       and the footer
</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar{
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
.container
{
   -ms-box-orient: vertical;
   display: -ms-flex;
   height: 100%;
   display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
   display: -moz-flex; 
   display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */ 
   display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */    

   -ms-flex-direction: column; 
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column; 
}
header, footer
{
    width: 300px;   
}
.content{
 width: 200px;   

}
    header
    {
        background: yellow;
    }
    .content
    {
        background: pink;

    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height:0;
    min-height: 0;
}
footer
{
    background: gray;
    height: 80px;
}
```

and changed the `width` but nothing happened. The new `div` stands on the bottom of the `content` `div`.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you put the `div`that you want to float? Could you put up an example where you include the markup & CSS that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DVAcV/28/)

Wrap your `content` div's text in another div `lft` with `float:left` css then wrap `lft` and `sidebar` divs to `content` div

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <header>Your header</header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="lft">Your text</div>
        <div class="sidebar">Your Sidebar content</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Your footer</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header, .content, footer {
    width: 300px;
}

.lft {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float properties on flex items are ignored. So, any float set on `.sidebar` or `.content` will not work. This is by design in the flexbox spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers.

You could work around this by wrapping the `.content` and `.sidebar` elements in another element, and then use either floats inside it, or set the wrapper element to be a flex container in the column direction. Example:

```
<header></header>
<div class="content"><!-- set this to be the flex item, eg. flex: 1 1 auto; -->
  <div class="content-inner"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div><!-- float this, for example. -->
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

The important point is that flexbox will only allow you to line up (and distribute & size) elements in 1 direction (row OR column). It can allow wrapping, but you can't divide flex items in both the column and row directions at once. If you need layouts like the one you describe, you need to nest stuff.

Comment: thanks, I wrap the content into another div and set float style to it. but it ruins everything. i think wrapping flex items by another div cause to remove flexbox.

Comment: You would need to set the flex properties of the new wrapper instead of the old one, of course. Children of that container can then be floated normally.

Comment: I dit it but float property ignored like before. can you show me in HTML and CSS markup?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVAcV/30/)

are you tring to do this

```
   *
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
.container
{
   -ms-box-orient: vertical;
   display: -ms-flex;
    width:400px;
   height: 100%;
   display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
   display: -moz-flex; 
   display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */ 
   display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */    

   -ms-flex-direction: column; 
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column; 
}
header, .content, footer
{
    width: 200px;   
}
header
{
    background: yellow;
}
.row{
    -ms-box-orient: vertical;
   display: -ms-flex;
    width:400px;
   height: 200px;
   display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
   display: -moz-flex; 
   display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */ 
   display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */    

   -ms-flex-direction: row; 
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row; 

}
.row,.content,.sidebar
{
    background: pink;

    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: auto;

}
footer
{
    background: gray;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I changed it. but where is the sidebar style?